# How can I make my own check box in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would love to use the:

```
Html.EditorFor(model => @Data.Test.Correct)
```

To create a checkbox.

However the source of my data is different from the data that needs to be updated. I know this may sound confusing but I get my data from a LINQ select query and then need to update in a different place.

The only way around this seems for me to hand code the HTML for the checkbox. But can someone give me an example of how I do this. For example, how can I code in the setting of checked=true?

Comment: im confused - what does rendering a checkbox have to do with updating data? It's your HTTP POST action method that needs to update the model. You can use `Html.CheckBoxFor` to render a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You may write HTML codes like below to create a selected or unselected checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="2" />
```

But you will need to write additional code manually to determine which checkbox should be selected, if your checkbox is dynamic generated or being filled in with stored data.